# With Mercurial, how to run a job for each changeset when doing an update?

Tags: mercurial, batch-processing, updates, changeset

**Question:** When I update my working directory from one revision to the other, I'd like to run a script for each revision passed. How can I do this?

**Important Constraints**

- The script is always the same
- Traversal should happen iteratively (I don't want to do all this by hand for 100 revisions...)
- The `incoming` hook is no option. It must happen not only after pushes or pulls, but for all updates, no matter how often I switch between revisions.

**For illustration:**

`r1(*) -- r2 -- r3 -- r4(head)`

Basically, I'd like to do

`r1(*) --> r2 (then run script) --> r3 (then run script) --> r4 (then...`

Let's say, my working directory is currently at `r1`, and now I want to update it to `r4`. Instead of doing a direct update (like with `hg update`), I'd like to update to `r2` first and then run a script (`update-my-database`, for example). Afterwards I'd like to update to `r3`, then run the same script and so on.

Comment: Hello, did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes, I think I did. Can I do something more than I did? If so, I'd like to do so. Your answer was truly helpful.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything more than accepting the answer. I am happy it was helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable but we must be careful to select a *linear* piece from the revision graph.

Consider a minimal repository with two heads (same thing would be if two branches or two bookmarks):

```
$ hg log -G --template "{rev}\n"
o  4
|
| o  3
| |
| o  2
|/
o  1
|
o  0
```

Say we start from 1. We want to go along either head 4 (so the linear piece would be: 1, 4) or along head 3 (so the linear piece would be: 1, 2, 3).

So we will use a script with two parameters: the beginning and the end of the linear piece.

This is bare-bones but works:

```
for rev in `hg log -r "descendants(1) and ancestors(3)" --template "{rev}\n"`
do
    echo Updating to $rev:
    hg update $rev
    echo Executing our script:
    hg id --id --num
done
```

Here is the output:

```
Updating to 1:
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
Executing our script:
4d5aba4313ce 1
Updating to 2:
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
Executing our script:
f0de0712ec00 2
Updating to 3:
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
Executing our script:
d052bd7c310b 3
```

The script works no matter what is the current revision of the working directory.

Before starting it, you have to do `hg fetch` to get the changes from the remote without applying them to the working directory and `hg log --graph` to understand the topology and so select the starting and ending points of the linear piece.

You also have to replace the hardcoded `1` and `3` with the `$1` and `$2` shell positional parameters and replace the `hg id` line with your actual script :-)

To understand how it works, we use a feature of mercurial called revsets (do `hg help revsets` to learn more) that allows to perform queries on the history graph (a bit like SQL :-)